# Object check not working in all browser

Tags: javascript

I have this javascript object

```
obj = {};
```

But the issue when I do something like this

```
if(user in obj)
```

It works fine on some browsers and I get this error on some browsers (ie. UCBrowser)

> (index):224 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'the_king-1' in null

Please how can I solve this? I Just want to check if a `key` is `in` the `obj`

Comment: `... in null` means, `obj` is `null`. Please add complete code here. [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps:

```
if (obj.hasOwnProperty(user))
```

... if you're simply checking for the property "on" the object.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty#Browser_compatibility